# 5.8 LAB: User-Defined Functions: Max magnitude

Tags: algorithm, function, logic, user-defined

Define a function named MaxMagnitude with two integer parameters that returns the largest magnitude value. Write a program that reads two integers from a user, calls function MaxMagnitude() with the inputs as arguments, and outputs the largest magnitude value.

Ex: If the inputs are:

5 7
the function returns and the program output is:

7
Ex: If the inputs are:

-8 -2
the function returns and the program output is:

-8
Note: The function does not just return the largest value, which for -8 -2 would be -2. Though not necessary, you may use the absolute value built-in math function: AbsoluteValue

I cannot seem to understand this problem.

Answer (score 0):

From my research, magnitude (of a number) refers to the largest absolute value of the input numbers.

|-8| is greater than |-2|, so it should be returned.

You need to calculate the largest absolute value from a given pair of numbers, in your case integers. The prompt said you had the option to use the AbsoluteValue function to make this process easier.

Hope this helped.

*Sample Code*

```js
var input1 = -8;
var input2 = -2;

function maxMagnitude(num1, num2) {
  var val1 = absoluteValue(num1);
  var val2 = absoluteValue(num2);
  if(val1 >= val2) {
    return num1;
  }
  else {
    return num2;
  }
}

function absoluteValue(int1) {
  if(int1 >= 0) {
    return int1;
  }
  else {
    var neg1 = -1;
    var returnedVal = int1 * neg1;
    return returnedVal;
  }
}

console.log(maxMagnitude(input1, input2));
```

Comment: * But make sure to return the input param itself, not its absolute value *

Answer (score 0):

```
Function MaxMagnitude(integer val1, integer val2) returns integer max
    //if absolute value of val1 is greater than that of val2,
    //max is set to val1, else max is set to val2
    if AbsoluteValue(val1) > AbsoluteValue(val2)
       max = val1
    else
       max = val2

Function Main() returns nothing
    //declare variables
    integer val1
    integer val2
    integer max
    //read two integers
    val1 = Get next input
    val2 = Get next input
    //find and display value with maximum magnitude
    max = MaxMagnitude(val1, val2)
    Put max to output
```